# Turn it on from here/there; it has been turned off from here/there

Tags: spoken-english

If we have to talk about turning off the switch by using the place (main switch; like something is connected to a secondary power socket, which is in turn connected to the main socket)

[image]

So something has been connected to this socket and this is connected to the main socket

Someone is trying turn on something by turning on the switch here but the main switch has been turned off. My question is whether the following uses of "from here" and "from there" are natural. Are they?

> It has been turned off from there. (while pointing there)
>
> It has been turned off from the main socket.

And what about:

> It has been turned off from here. (you are standing there and telling this to the other person)
>
> You can turn it on from here.
>
> You can turn it on from there.

Comment: Please do not ask individuals leaving comments to answer your question.

Comment: @jan I disagree. i think "from" is better left in than removed from the examples in the question.

Answer (score 1):

All of the listed forms are perfectly acceptable and feel natural to me.

> It has been turned off from the main socket.

could also be

> It has been turned off at the main socket.

and i think that usage is more common, but "at" cannot be use in thagt way with '="here" or "there".

In the form

> You can turn it on from here.

I would be inclined to omit "from" saying only

> You can turn it on here.

but I would not be inclined to omit "from" in the other forms, although one could do so, provided that the statement is not ambiguous in context.

Comment: I thought we only connect something to or disconnect it from a socket, not turning them on or off! Is it really idiomatic to say turn this on at the socket or something like this? I am a bit confused!

Comment: So it sounds natural to you, right?

Comment: It seems all your examples are about a _socket,_ where you plug something in or out. Would you also use "from" for a _switch,_ which you turn on or off?

Comment: Well, can't it mean "switch" as well?

Comment: And @DavidSiegel , what is the sentence that you think is more common  "from" or "at"? ("and i think that usage is more common, but "at" cannot be use in thagt way with '="here" or "there".")

Comment: @Cardinal the kind of grouped sockets pictured often come with a switch controlling the group. I take "tun off at the socket" to mean using such a switch.

Comment: @It's I have heard both 'from" and "at" used in this way. I  have probably used both. I have no clear impression which is more frequent. Either should be acceptable, its a matter of style.

Comment: @DavidSiegel I see, but OP says "So something has been connected to this socket and this is connected to the main socket", so I thought OP means the multi-outlet extension cable is unplugged from the main socket, not that the switch on the device is off.

Comment: @Cardinal perhaps. I read "connected"  in the sense of "a connection  exists" not "a connection is now being made". It is often used in both senses. OP's question could be read in either way, but it does speak of a "main switch " and does not speak of "plugging in" which is why I read it as I did.

Comment: So it can be both :"It has been turned off from the main socket" or "It has been turned off at the main socket", right?             And others are: "You can turn it on here" ( or "from here") etc.....

Comment: @It's yes any of those forms can be used, and the choice is one of style, not grammar.